# Error while inserting UUID array with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, postgresql-10

I have an attribute in one of my entity class as below

```
@Column(name = "idc_reviewer", columnDefinition="_uuid[]")
private UUID[] reviewer;
```

While saving the entity, I am getting below error.

```
ERROR: column "idc_reviewer" is of type uuid[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I tried replacing columnDefinition with pg-uuid[] but that too didn't work.

**Software Version:**
Hibernate: 5.2.17
SpringBoot: 2.0.3

Comment: How do you expect that postgres will store an array in a table column?

Comment: @M.Deinum: because Postgres [supports it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) (but apparently Hibernate does not)

Comment: Hmm... Learned something new :). You probably need a custom type for this then. And of course Vlad has you already covered (see https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: @M.Deinum If there is no other approach, Thats a last option for me :)

Comment: Try adding [my library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor) to your dependencies. UUID types are something I haven't actually tested, so I'm curious of the result.